# Is there a way to copy the UV transforms of one hand in a character mesh to the UVs of another hand in the same mesh without using a mirror modifier?

Tags: mesh, texturing, uv

Referring to the image, I would like the UVs in the right hand to match the look of the UVs on the left hand.
[image: Picture of UVs on hands]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They look like they already do, it's looks like a scaling issue. Scale the right hand to match the size of the left, I think they'll stretch out and be nearly the same.

Comment: I know I could scale the UVs and sculpt them to the shape of the hand. I'm just looking for a way to save time by copy and pasting the UVs. The UVs are too large to copy and paste, so the solution would be to split the right hand UVs apart, copy and paste the UVs, and then stitch them together. I just don't know how I can accomplish this complicated process the best way.